# Higher order functions in Erlang

Tags: erlang, higher-order-functions

How to write the following higher order Haskell function in Erlang?

```
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a  
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
1> Apply2 = fun(F, X) -> F(F(X)) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.82930912>
2> F = fun(Arg) -> Arg * 2 end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.82930912>
3> Apply2(F, 10).
40
```

The problem is that, I'm not sure if it's what you actually need. Cause in Haskell, you can use `applyTwice f` as function, but not in Erlang (there is no built-in `partial` or `curry` functionality). You also can't do in Erlang something like

```
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a  
applyTwice f = f . f
```

Comment: Do we have curried form in Erlang?

Comment: @Coffe_Mug There is no syntax sugar to deal with currying. Of coure you can write function that will return function with necessary scope, but... it's hard to write and read.

Comment: @Coffe_Mug Also as Erlang functions with the same same and different *arity* (number of args) are **different** functions then currying becomes messy.